# Scrapy Response bandwidth

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-request

I am trying to log bandwidth used by each request, using Custom Middleware. Following code is used

```
class CustomDownloaderMiddleware(CustomMiddleware):
    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        if response.url.startswith("http"):
            logging.info("{}: {}".format(response.url,len(response.body)))
            
        return response
```

Instead of body size band width is  what i am looking for. But I don't find Content-Length in response.headers. Is there any way ?

Response header

```
{b'Date': [b'Sat, 08 Aug 2020 17:26:36 GMT'], b'Expires': [b'-1'], b'Cache-Control': [b'private, max-age=0'], b'Content-Type': [b'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'], b'P3P': [b'CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."'], b'Server': [b'gws'], b'X-Xss-Protection': [b'0'], b'X-Frame-Options': [b'SAMEORIGIN'], b'Set-Cookie': [b'1P_JAR=2020-08-08-17; expires=Mon, 07-Sep-2020 17:26:36 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; Secure', b'NID=204=ht_pjEdFKBPiysMsQU8szq9znBhhZKMmgm20Pzdoi23gok-Zqb9qS91cmmyuN-Ba19DL9DV1L2iDLS2q9FJTsK7j83e7Bovd78HPstAUkZyJ7hci0VGyUzaU9T0IEjvqXu4KxG-Os034z7ytUf7wzFaVJzrrFyuA34MJ1H1dTGo; expires=Sun, 07-Feb-2021 17:26:36 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly'], b'Alt-Svc': [b'h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"']}
```

Thanks

Comment: show response.headers

Comment: @frozen response headers added to question

Comment: I think you will have to recreate the raw response from `response` fields (`body`, `method`, `headers`) taking the HTTP/1.1 specs into account. That’s the most accurate you can get, I think. Same for requests, if you want to account for upload.